# solidity wont compile contract from ethereum blog

Tags: wallets

I am trying to build tokens in Ethereum
when i tried to paste the referenced code into Ethereum wallet i get:

I have been all over the web and can't find a specific reference to this error. The code fails in the online solidity compiler. I could not get the new online compiler to load in chrome under win10.

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSLna.png]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are referring to the code at the bottom of the page in [Create a cryptocurrency contract in Ethereum](https://ethereum.org/token).

It is due to some recent changes to the [Solidity compiler 0.4.0](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.0) including:

> - Change _ to _; in modifiers.

Here's the working source code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }

contract token {
    /* Public variables of the token */
    string public standard = 'Token 0.1';
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function token(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        if (!msg.sender.send(msg.value)) throw;                         // Send back any ether sent accidentally
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }

    /* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        return true;
    }

    /* Approve and then comunicate the approved contract in a single tx */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        returns (bool success) {    
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;   // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /* This unnamed function is called whenever someone tries to send ether to it */
    function () {
        throw;     // Prevents accidental sending of ether
    }
}

contract MyAdvancedToken is owned, token {

    uint256 public sellPrice;
    uint256 public buyPrice;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyAdvancedToken(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol,
        address centralMinter
    ) token (initialSupply, tokenName, decimalUnits, tokenSymbol) {
        if(centralMinter != 0 ) owner = centralMinter;      // Sets the owner as specified (if centralMinter is not specified the owner is msg.sender)
        balanceOf[owner] = initialSupply;                   // Give the owner all initial tokens
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        if (frozenAccount[msg.sender]) throw;                // Check if frozen
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }


    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (frozenAccount[_from]) throw;                        // Check if frozen            
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;   // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
        Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
    }

    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }

    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }

    function buy() {
        uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                // calculates the amount
        if (balanceOf[this] < amount) throw;               // checks if it has enough to sell
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;                   // adds the amount to buyer's balance
        balanceOf[this] -= amount;                         // subtracts amount from seller's balance
        Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);                // execute an event reflecting the change
    }

    function sell(uint256 amount) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < amount ) throw;        // checks if the sender has enough to sell
        balanceOf[this] += amount;                         // adds the amount to owner's balance
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;                   // subtracts the amount from seller's balance
        if (!msg.sender.send(amount * sellPrice)) {        // sends ether to the seller. It's important
            throw;                                         // to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
        } else {
            Transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);            // executes an event reflecting on the change
        }               
    }
}
```

Where I added a `;` after the `_` in:

```
    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _;
    }
```

I've also added a check to get rid of a warning:

```
        if (!msg.sender.send(msg.value)) throw;                         // Send back any ether sent accidentally
```

Here's a screenshot of the code working in Ethereum Wallet v0.8.6:

[image]

And here's a screenshot of the code working in Solidity Online connected to my local Dev `geth` node:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. this community is awesome!

Comment: The Ethereum Foundation has been notified of this bug and will hopefully fix it.